# How to migrate all app data to a different device. No root

Tags: android, apk

I need to migrate all the data available (including logged user info, etc) from an app in Android to a different device. Basically what I need is to export entire App from one device to another (maybe more than 1 device) including all app's data

Comment: Hello! Is this your own app? or is a third party app?

Comment: It's a third party app @BernardoMorales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is not your own app, you will have some trouble if the application isn't "debuggeable"...

To avoid this you will have to unpack the APK,
 For this I suggest using Apktools, works like a charm: [Apktools](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/)

Inside the unpacked APK, Modify the AndroidManifest.xml:

Inside the `<application>` entry, add or replace the value with: `android:debuggable="true"`
After that, you will need to **rebuild** the app and **sign it again in order to avoid conflicts**. Apktools will do the job again.

Now, you will be able to explore all the data folders using the `adb shell` command an then `run-as <package name>`

Just copy all files from `/data/data/<package name>` to `/sdcard/.` (which is a free to access location).

Then **exit the adb shell** and use the pull command as follows: `adb pull /sdcard/<package name>`

This will download all the data inside the current directory, at this point, we have all the data we need, now we must do the opposite process to let everything ready to work.

Install the new APK (debbugeable one we just built back) with:

```
adb install -r newAPK.apk
```

Push the previously downloaded data to the new device using: 
`adb push <package name> /sdcard/<package name>` 
 now with the accessible data inside the device, and then run:

```
adb shell run-as <package name> mv /sdcard/<package name> /data/data/.
```

After this, all the data is correctly placed and the app should not realize the device change, with everything configured as expected.

I hope this solve your issue. Greetings!

Comment: This prevents the app from being updated in the future, though (because the signatures no longer match).

Comment: @JensNeubauer that's right, but not an issue for this case. It's a third party app that won't need any update in the future.